# what is the correct way to sort list of items by using a select list

Tags: javascript, php, html, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

Lets say I have a sorting list like this

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropSortbtn2"> Food <i class="bi bi-caret-down"></i></button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Tomato</a>
                <a href="#">APPle</a>
                <a href="#">Carrot</a>
                <a href="#">Broccoli</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I want that drop down list to sort list of items and hide others,

so for example if I have this list

```
<ul>
  <li>Tomato</li>
  <li>APPle</li>
  <li>Broccoli</li>
  <li>Carrot</li>
  <li>Tomato</li>
  <li>Broccoli</li>
</ul>
```

And the user click tomato in the drop down list, all items should be hidden and only tomato elements will be shown. What is the correct way to do this ? knowing that the sorting drop down list will be really long.

Comment: Is that your full code? Your "drop down list" does not currently look like a dropdown.

Comment: This is a customized dropdown list where div and a tags look like drop down list. I did it like this to make more styles to the drop down lists since the styles to <select> and <option> tags are really limited

Comment: Can you provide the CSS and JS then?

Comment: I didn't write any javascript codes, but here is the css and html component https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `click` event listener to all select options that loops through each `li` in the `ul` and hides those whose `textContent` is not equal to the `textContent` of the select option clicked.

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .dropdown-content a')
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');

options.forEach(f => f.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let text = this.textContent;
  listItems.forEach(e => e.style.display = e.textContent == text ? "block" : "none")
}))
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropSortbtn2"> Food <i class="bi bi-caret-down"></i></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Tomato</a>
    <a href="#">APPle</a>
    <a href="#">Carrot</a>
    <a href="#">Broccoli</a>
  </div>
</div>

<ul id="list">
  <li>Tomato</li>
  <li>APPle</li>
  <li>Broccoli</li>
  <li>Carrot</li>
  <li>Tomato</li>
  <li>Broccoli</li>
</ul>
```